# How to find the value of selected index in dropdownlist in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Case_Id" DataValueField="Case_Id" Height="16px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="184px">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

and C# code is

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    cmd.CommandText = "Select * from tb5 where Case_Id="+Convert.ToInt64(DropDownList1.SelectedIndex);
    SqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    bool b = r.Read();
    TextBox2.Text = r["Case_Name"].ToString();
    TextBox2.ReadOnly = false;
}
```

Comment: `DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value` ??

Comment: What the error message you received? 
In this instruction: Convert.ToInt64(DropDownList1.SelectedIndex)
You are converting a String To Int to concatenate to another string. You don't need to do that. Just eliminate the convert:
cmd.CommandText = "Select * from tb5 where Case_Id="+ DropDownList1.SelectedIndex;
If this doesn't work, try to use the .Value

Answer (score 2):

You're missing `AutoPostBack="true"` in markup

Secondly, you're getting index of selected item which means that you're getting number 0 for first selected item, 1 for second etc. which probably doesn't match with your ID's.

Change your code behind like this:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    cmd.CommandText = "Select * from tb5 where Case_Id= @CaseId";
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CaseId", SqlDbType.BigInt)).Value = Convert.ToInt64(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
    SqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    bool b = r.Read();
    TextBox2.Text = r["Case_Name"].ToString();
    TextBox2.ReadOnly = false;
}
```

Comment: An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: @NomanNomeButt parameter type was Int but should be `BigInt` if you're using `long` / `int64` as Id. I have edited my answer. If it still throws exception - that could be few things: your drop down doesn't contain values that can be converted to `int64` (such as letters) or nothing is selected